# Arrow function inside map operator/method in javascript explanation e => e.target.value

Tags: javascript

I am following a tutorial in javascript/angular2 and I know it is a novice question, but if someone could please explain what exactly is this piece of code doing. I have read at various places and in the Mozilla docs, but I am still confused about it. I am aware that: *map calls a provided callback function once for each element in an array, in order, and constructs a new array from the results*,but what exactly is the code doing in this context:

```
map(e => e.target.value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nearly the same as this:

```
map(function(e) {
    return e.target.value;
});
```

...it's just using the *concise arrow function* form instead of a `function` function. There are other differences between `function` functions and arrow functions (arrow functions *close over* `this` and a couple of other things, `function` functions don't), but that code isn't using any of them.

Answer (score 0):

This is using ES2015/ES6 shorthand syntax. To write it out in ES5:

`map(function(e) { return e.target.value; })`

The function is the callback function, the `e` is the current element of the array, and the return value of `e.target.value` will be the value put in the new array.